# Alternative of bg.set function in opencv 3

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I am getting an error when I am trying to execute the below-mentioned code of line
by using OpenCV 3 version.

```
bg.set("nmixtures", 10);
```

> Error bg object does not have any member name .set

Can anybody tell me how to use the same function in OpenCV 3 version

Comment: Please tag the language you're programming in.

Comment: How was bg created?, you should add the code necessary to reproduce the error. This way you may get a faster and better answer.

Comment: I created object by using -> Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> bg = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(20, 16, true); and i am using c++ language

Answer (score 0):

The right way:

```
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2* bgsegm = bg.dynamicCast<cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2>();
    if (bgsegm)
    {
            bgsegm->setNMixtures(10);
    }
```